# Переменная JS на странице JSP cеттится значением только после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, сессия

В моем сервлете следующий код сеттит сессионный атрибут:

`session.setAttribute("culturesJsonArray", CommonUtils.toJson(foundLanguage.getCultures()));`

Эта перменнная в js коде на странице jsp должна его принимать:

`<script>let cultures = ${sessionScope.culturesJsonArray};</script>`

Сначала происходит вызов сервлета, а затем переменная js должна сетиться. При первой загрузке страницы переменная сеттится пустым значением `[]` и только после перезагрузки страницы переменная загружается json'ом. Какова последовательность загрузки jsp страниц и обновлением session аттрибутов? В этом ли проблема?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что вызов AJAX и ответ не обновляют DOM и, поэтому, сессионные атрибуты не были видны на странице, а были только после её обновления. Я решил проблему тем, что отправил сессионные атрибуты в response сервлета следующим образом:

```
PrintWriter out = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
String page = PagesManager.getProperty("page.languageEditorCultures");
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
attributes.put(
"cultures", CommonUtils.convertListOfObjectsToJson(foundLanguage.getCultures())
);
Response response = new Response(page, attributes);
String jsonResponse = CommonUtils.convertObjectToJson(response);
out.print(jsonResponse);
```

А на странице JSP создал элементы с помощью JQuery и вставил туда сессионные атрибуты

(Response мой кастомный класс, который имеет поля `pageName` и `attributes`)